# If $p \in\mathbb{R}^n$, $r > 0$, and $U = \{x \in\mathbb{R}^n \mid\|p-x\| > r\}$, then $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, logic, algebraic-topology

Prove or give a counterexample: if $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $r > 0$, and $U = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; | \; ||p − x|| > r\}$, then $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I think that it should be open but I can't figure out how to prove it.

The definition of open I am  using is for every $x \in U$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that  $B(x, \delta)$ is a subset of $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Axel said, you can show $B(0,r)$ is closed. You can also show the openness directly. Suppose $y\in U$ and let $\delta = ||y-p||-r$. You may show this $\delta$ works.

Edit: Let $y \in U = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; | \; ||p − x|| > r\}$ and set $\delta = ||y-p||-r$. Then for any $z\in B(y,\delta)$, we have$||z-p|| = ||(z-y)+(y-p)||\\\quad\quad\quad\,\geq ||\,||y-p||-||z-y||\,||
\\\quad\quad\quad\,=||y-p||-||z-y||>||y-p||-\delta = r$

so we have $B(y,\delta) \subset U$. And therefore $U$ is open.

Comment: can you expand on how to use this delta to show that the ball is a subset? I can't seem to make my math work?

Answer (score 0):

Let $W = \mathbb{R}^n \backslash U$ then $W = \mathcal{B}(0,r) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; | \; || p-x||\leq r\}$ is by definition a closed ball, and you can show that a closed ball is always a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore its complement that is $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If you are not at ease with my first explanation, try to draw it in two dimensions : here $U$ is the portion of the plan the outside of the circle centered in $p $ with radius $r$. Take a point $q = (x,y) \in U $ and start to draw a circle that would stay in $U$, i.e. that will not intersect with your first circle.

[image]

Hint : you can take for the radius of your second circle $ \delta = \frac{1}{2}(||p-q||-r)$, you can choose also $\delta = ||p-q||-r$ as @Kevin John suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=|x-p|$. Since $f$ is continuous, preimages of open sets are open. Since $(r, \infty )$ is open, $f^{-1}(r, \infty )$ is too. This is exactly the set in the question.